# Align Text left of the floating right part of paragraph

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, text-align

I need to give some floated right text same start position. I have multiple p and every p is divided in two span. The initial span are floated left and seconds are floated right.

Some HTML and Image to be more clear about.

```css
.card {
  max-width: 20rem;
  border: 1px solid #004d99;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.card-header {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #004d99;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
}

.card-header input {
  border: 2px #004d99 solid;
}

.card-header span {
  color: #90ee90;
}

.card-header span i {
  margin-left: 3%;
}

.card-body {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.card-body p span:first-child {
   float: left;
 }

.card-body p span:last-child {
    float: right; text-align: left;
 }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card col-md-3 text-dark bg-light m-3">
  <div class="card-header">
    <input class="form-check-input chk" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckDefault"> Stato: Pubblicato <span> &#11044 </span><i class="far fa-file-alt"></i>11 <i class="fas fa-eye"></i>&nbsp;112
  </div>

  <div class="card-body">
        <p>
            <span >Nome:</span>
            <span >Lotto Prova</span>
        </p>
        <p>
            <span>Data Pubblicazione:</span>
            <span>10/12/2021</span>
        </p>
        <p>
            <span>Data di Scadenza:</span>
            <span>25/12/2021</span>
        </p>
        <p>
            <span>Accesso:</span>
            <span>Link</span>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I have:

[image: Bad Align]

What I need:

[image: Right align]

Thanks to who will answer!

Comment: Avoid to use float property, now you can achieve this by using grid or flexbox. For example, it seems you are using bootstap... if you use version 4 you have flex utilities., read the docs about it

Comment: Your card body is tabular data so why not use a `table` or at least CSS-Tables - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/xxqJMNg

Comment: @Paulie_D This is a nice and clean option too, but when i resize the page the data inside the table walk out outside the card body. I also tryed to give a max-width to card body, but it doesn't seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, this type of content is a typical example where you *can*  use a table, and its default settings will do exactly what you are asking for. So I modified your code accordingly, using CSS-table `display` parameters (but you could as well use actual HTML table/tr/td/th tags, then you wouldn't need that CSS and it would semantically be better).

Note: I erased your inline-styles for the spans, and I also erased the `md-3` class from the card, since otherwise the content simply wouldn't fit into the card line-per-line, but cause breaks due to the limited width, at least here in the snippet (different on wide screens).

```css
.card {
  border: 1px solid #004d99;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 300px;
}

.card-header {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #004d99;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
}

.card-header input {
  border: 2px #004d99 solid;
}

.card-header span {
  color: #90ee90;
}

.card-header span i {
  margin-left: 3%;
}

.card-body {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  display: table;
}
.card-body > p {
  display: table-row;
}
.card-body > p > span {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card text-dark bg-light m-3">
  <div class="card-header">
    <input class="form-check-input chk" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckDefault"> Stato: Pubblicato <span> &#11044 </span><i class="far fa-file-alt"></i>11 <i class="fas fa-eye"></i>&nbsp;112
  </div>

  <div class="card-body">
    <p>
      <span>Nome:</span>
      <span>Lotto Prova</span>
    </p>
    <p>
      <span>Data Pubblicazione:</span>
      <span>10/12/2021</span>
    </p>
    <p>
      <span>Data di Scadenza:</span>
      <span>25/12/2021</span>
    </p>
    <p>
      <span>Accesso:</span>
      <span>Link</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with flexbox and simplify the HTML in the process.

Remove the inline style from the `span` elements and setup the CSS to make the flex children take up exactly half the space. This will give you the layout you're looking for.

```css
.card-body>p {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.card-body>p>* {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card col-md-3 text-dark bg-light m-3" style="max-width: 20rem; border: 1px solid #004d99; border-radius: 20px;">
  <div class="card-header" style="background-color: #fff; border-bottom: 1px solid #004d99; border-top-left-radius: 20px; border-top-right-radius: 20px;">
    <input style="border: 2px #004d99 solid;" class="form-check-input chk" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckDefault"> Stato: Pubblicato <span style="color: #90ee90;"> &#11044 </span><i class="far fa-file-alt" style="margin-left: 3%;"></i>11 <i class="fas fa-eye"
      style="margin-left: 3%;"></i>&nbsp;112
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <p><span>Nome:</span><span>Lotto Prova</span></p>
    <p><span>Data Pubblicazione:</span><span>10/12/2021</span></p>
    <p><span>Data di Scadenza:</span><span>25/12/2021</span></p>
    <p><span>Accesso:</span><span>Link</span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not use the classes that Bootstrap provides? Custom styles should be a last resort when using a layout library.

Comment: I agree with you for the most part. I tend to prefer simple solutions which is why I suggested this method. Easy to debug. To each their own though 

Comment: Adding a couple classes seems simpler to me than creating more code to maintain. Also, you have improperly nested markup involving the paragraphs.

Comment: It depends on how you work with everything in the ecosystem. I use SCSS to compile everything down to one file. Only using the parts of Bootstrap that are necessary in my application.